# HP FlexFabric 5700 (Comware) VLAN 1-to-1 Mapping. ISP assigned vlan I already use

Tags: vlan, hp, hp-comware

I have a new feed from an ISP, that would be slow to respond to any change requests.

They tagged this drop with a vlan ID of 10, which I happen to already be using on my switches.

I want a brand new vlan (let's say 33) for this.

Is it possible on HP flexfabric to take this feed, strip the 10 and put it in 33 on my side?

This is working (but undesired):

```
interface T1/0/2
port link-type trunk
port trunk permit vlan 10
```

I can then put a VirtualMachine in Vlan10 or even assign a VLAN-Interface10 on the switch itself and ping the ISP's gateway.

What I WANT to do is essentially retag anything coming in on vlan 10, as vlan 33 on my side - and vice versa. With loads of reading I tried this:

(Vlan 10 already exists on my side, Vlan 33 is new)

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 33 10
 vlan mapping 33 translated-vlan 10
```

or

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 33 10
 vlan mapping 10 translated-vlan 33
```

Have also tried inserting both vlan mapping statements.

I've also tried various iterations of a hybrid port and setting 10 as tagged and 33 as untagged & vice-versa.

I feel like I'm missing something silly and driving myself mad.

Is there anyone that could provide some insight?

## Edit: more complete configs

```
vlan 33
 description New VLAN on my side
vlan 10
 description Existing VLAN on my side. ISP's new drop has this tagged the same
```

### ==Standard VLAN ATTEMPT== Working!

In this port is the drop from my ISP:

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description ISP DROP
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 10
```

In this port is a trunk with vlan 10:

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/21
 description VMUPLINK
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 10 200 300 400 601
#
```

Simple access port:

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/22
 description Test VLAN10
 port access vlan 10
#
```

Test Vlan interface in existing VLAN 10

```
interface Vlan-interface10
 ip address 142.84.55.62 255.255.255.252
```

I can now ping 142.84.55.61 (IP modified for the internet but it is indeed a /30) from:

1. The Vlan interface
2. the access port 2/0/22
3. a VM in a Port Group assigned vlan id 10

### ==VLAN MAPPING ATTEMPT== Not working!

In this port is the drop from my ISP:

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 description ISP DROP
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 33 10
 vlan mapping 10 translated-vlan 33
```

In this port is a trunk with vlan 33 and a vlan in it:

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/21
 description VMUPLINK
 port link-type trunk
 undo port trunk permit vlan 1
 port trunk permit vlan 33 200 300 400 601
#
```

This port is a simple access port in 33

```
interface Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/22
 description Test VLAN33
 port access vlan 33
#
```

Attempted Vlan interface in New VLAN 33

```
interface Vlan-interface33
 ip address 142.84.55.62 255.255.255.252
```

I can't ping 142.84.55.61 (IP modified for the internet but it is indeed a /30) from neither:

1. The Vlan interface
2. the access port 2/0/22
3. a VM in a Port Group assigned vlan id 33

Comment: Hybrid-mode port and untagged VLANs won't get you anywhere. The bit with `vlan mapping 10 translated-vlan 33` looks about right - where's the problem? Have you checked the MAC table on that port with the desired VLAN? You did configure another port into VLAN 33 as well, didn't you?

Comment: Whether I try a [new] Vlan interface (in what is now 33) or stick a machine into a port designed for 33 - I can no longer ping the same gateway.

Comment: Have you explicitly created both VLANs?

Comment: Yes, or it wouldn't let me add them to the permitted list nor create a vlan interface in it :)

Comment: Please add the complete configuration to your question and tell us where everything is connected. Also make sure the configured translations show up with `display vlan mapping`.

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: Looks OK to me - what does the MAC table show for VLAN pre and post translation?

Comment: It shows the ISP's CPE MaC address in VLAN 33 as well as my test devices in 33 - when attempting translation mode.

And clearly, vlan 10 for the lot when in a normal trunk.

Comment: You're questioning now leads me to believe, the ISP is basically expecting a vlan tag of 10. Looking at the circuit ID info I have:


`interface ge1/0.10
description Interface ge1/0.10 Circuit ID XXXXXXXXXX vlan 10
encapsulation dot1Q 10`

But if the MAC table is showing 3... surely they'll never decapsulate it correctly?

Comment: In other words, its not like NAT and translating them back. And not like I have control of their CPE. I need it to translate outside's VLAN 10 to my inner VLAN 3 on ingress. And my inner VLAN 3 to outside VLAN 10 on egress.

Comment: No, it's translating backwards as well - `vlan mapping 10 translated-vlan 33` translates an external VLID 10 to internal VLID 33 both ways. You can see this by capturing on the translated port externally. If you can see the CPE's MAC in VLAN 33 that's fine. Any ACLs/ARP/port restrictions in the config?

Comment: none. no such concepts used on this switch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134652/discussion-between-zac67-and-daniel-sputnikk).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a problem with `vlan mapping 10 translated-vlan 33` - that translates an incoming VLID 10 on that port to VLID 33 for internal and further external use, and vice versa.

Troubleshooting steps:

- make sure the CPE's MAC address shows up in the switch's MAC table in VLAN 33 as well as the pinging/test host
- if `ping` fails, check whether ARP works: the CPE's IP address needs to be associated with its MAC address in the local ARP cache of the pinging host
- if you've got access to the CPE, it should also show an ARP entry for the pinging host
- if everything fails, connect a switch with tagged VLAN 10 and port mirroring/monitoring in between the 5700 and the CPE - a packet capture should show you exactly what is going on
- alternatively, you could connect another VLAN-capable device with tagged VLAN 10 and test connectivity